# How to generate and save to file SummaryReport or any other JMeter Report

Tags: api, jmeter

I have created simple JMeter Test and i don't know how to generate and save some kind of JMeter report(Summary Report, View results in Table e.t.c) to some file.

My code looks like this: 
public class JMeterTest extends BaseScenario{

```
protected void scenario() throws Exception { 
    // Engine 
    StandardJMeterEngine jm = new StandardJMeterEngine(); 
    // jmeter.properties 
    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("D:/Java Tools/JMeter/apache-jmeter-2.11/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/jmeter.properties"); 

    HashTree hashTree = new HashTree(); 

    // HTTP Sampler 
    HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler(); 
    httpSampler.setDomain("192.168.67.98"); 
    httpSampler.setPort(8080); 
    httpSampler.setPath("/gks-server"); 
    httpSampler.setMethod("GET"); 

    // Loop Controller 
    TestElement loopCtrl = new LoopController(); 
    ((LoopController)loopCtrl).setLoops(1); 
    ((LoopController)loopCtrl).addTestElement(httpSampler); 
    ((LoopController)loopCtrl).setFirst(true); 

    // Thread Group 
    SetupThreadGroup threadGroup = new SetupThreadGroup(); 
    threadGroup.setNumThreads(1); 
    threadGroup.setRampUp(1); 
    threadGroup.setSamplerController((LoopController)loopCtrl); 

    TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("MY TEST PLAN"); 
    testPlan.setTestPlanClasspath("D:/JMeterTestPlan/test.jmx"); 

    hashTree.add("testPlan", testPlan); 
    hashTree.add("loopCtrl", loopCtrl); 
    hashTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup); 
    hashTree.add("httpSampler", httpSampler); 

    jm.configure(hashTree); 

    //Run TEST 
    jm.run(); 
}
```

}

Please Help Me! 
With Best Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following few lines before your `jm.run()` statement:

```
Summariser summer = null;
String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");//$NON-NLS-1$
if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
    summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
}

String logFile = "/path/to/output/file.jtl";
ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
logger.setFilename(logFile);
hashTree.add(hashTree.getArray()[0], logger);
```

All the output will go to `/path/to/output/file.jtl` in CSV format. You can look into `jmeter.properties` file in /bin folder of your JMeter installation to identify which "interesting" values are required and override them appropriately.

Available options are:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=none
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.encoding=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.filename=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=,
jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=\t
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.xml_pi=<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../extras/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl"?>
jmeter.save.saveservice.base_prefix=~/
jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=false
```

See [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide for details on how to run JMeter tests from Java code and more.

Comment: Thank you Dmitriy, i've uncommented option in jmeter.properties and added your code to my Class. But i have error FATAL_E 2014-07-29 18:11:49.532 [jmeter.s] (): Bad saveservice properties file
java.io.FileNotFoundException: null\bin\saveservice.properties (The system cannot find the path specified) now. I try to add JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("D:/Java Tools/JMeter/apache-jmeter-2.11/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/saveservice.properties"); But its  not work. Thank you

Comment: That's weird however you can try adding the following line after JMeterEngine initialization: `JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("D:/Java Tools/JMeter/apache-jmeter-2.11/apache-jmeter-2.11/");`

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Result of test was displayed in the console(example: summary =     10 in     6s =    1.8/s Avg:  5086 Min:  4633 Max:  5520 Err:     0 (0.00%))

Comment: But in the logFile( String logFile = "D:/JMeterTestPlan/report.jtl";) results are absent, only Logs. How i can to write result to this file also? Best Regards

Comment: If you see something like `1406537035038,440,,200,OK, 1-1,text,true,1610,413` - it's results. Open this `report.jtl` file with the listener of your choice and if the data is enough JMeter will display it.

Comment: Yes, i see in log file this: 2014/07/30 12:39:23.335, 3596, 200, OK, 1-1, text, true, 16275, 10, 10, http://www.autostop.lviv.ua/, 3577, utf-8, 1, 0, w7IgorMy, 0.    But i want to see this : "(example: summary = 10 in 6s = 1.8/s Avg: 5086 Min: 4633 Max: 5520 Err: 0 (0.00%))"

Comment: These messages are going to jmeter.log file. If not, uncomment `summariser.log=true` property in jmeter.properties file.

Comment: Uncommented summarized.log=true, but this not help me

Comment: Stackoverflow complains that the discussion is too long. Try searching for jmeter.log file not in Jmeter home but in the root of your Java project.

Answer (score 0):

this report is fine when files are less than 100MB, bigger files take a lot of time to get processed or they do not get processed by xpath.

Better solution is to use jtl file and CMDRunner.ext to create different files.

Wiht this function you can easy create different graphs with cmdrunner for specific services:
http://performancewebautoamtionother.blogspot.si/2015/12/jmeter-create-graphs-with-cmdrunner.html